# Link inside Link web method

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

Hi i am trying to navigate through anchor link. Only the first link works. For example if i click a link in a page it goes to that link, but when there is another link in page whcih i have clicked it doesnt work. And also the second has the same class 1st link Please help.

```
 $('#frmDisplay').on('load', function () {
               $('#frmDisplay a.anchorLink').on('click', function () {
                     var id = $(this).attr('id');
                     var hid = document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>');
                     hid.value = id;
                     $.ajax({
                         type: "POST",
                         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                         url: "Amm.aspx/getlink",
                         data: "{'Id': '" + id + "'}",
                         dataType: "json",
                         success: function (data) {
                             $('#frmDisplay').contents().find('html').html(data.d);
                         },
                         error: function (response) {
                             alert(response.responseText);
                         }
                     });
                 });
             });
 public static string getlink(int Id)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connString"].ConnectionString);
            string link = "extlink";
            BookTree obj = new BookTree();
            DataSet ds = obj.getlink(Id);
            SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("select vcFilePath from tblBookNodes where iModuleId='" + Id + "'",conn);
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                bytes = (byte[])dr["vcFilePath"];
            }
            string fileName = link.Replace(" ", "_") + ".htm";
            // DirectoryInfo strPath = new DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/Linking/"));
            //string strPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"/Linking/") + fileName;
            //foreach (FileInfo file in strPath.GetFiles())
            //{
            //  file.Delete();
            //}
            string path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/htmlFile/"), fileName);
            var doc = new HtmlDocument();
            string html = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
            doc.LoadHtml(html);
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            var hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(path);
            sWriter.Write(sw.ToString());
            doc.Save(sWriter);
            sWriter.Close();
            //string fileContents = html;
            //System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, html);
            return File.ReadAllText(path);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use "on" instead of find() and event listener attach.
Please refer to this example:

```
$('#formDisplay a.anchroLink').on('click', function() {
  // TODO: handle the click
})
```

This is necessary because when you add the event listener the DOM is not yet ready to handle requests for non existing content. Using ["on"](https://api.jquery.com/on/) you can attach an event to a class or a simple DOM query.

To be more clear I post your code with modifications based on my previous suggestion:

```
$('#frmDisplay a.anchorLink').on('click', function () {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var hid = document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>');
  hid.value = id;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "Amm.aspx/getlink",
    data: "{'Id': '" + id + "'}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
      $('#frmDisplay').contents().find('html').html(data.d)
    },
    error: function (response) {
      alert(response.responseText);
    }
  });
});
```

My last answer (I don't know you were using iFrames):

```
function clickHandler() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var hid = document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>');
  hid.value = id;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "Amm.aspx/getlink",
    data: "{'Id': '" + id + "'}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {                         
      $('#frmDisplay').contents().find('html').html(data.d);
      // You can reload the event handler because the prev one
      // has been lost after refreshing the page with the ajax call.
      $('#frmDisplay').contents()
        .find('a.anchorLink')
        .click(clickHandler);
    },
    error: function (response) {
      alert(response.responseText);
    }
  });
}
$('#frmDisplay').on('load', function () {
  $('#frmDisplay')
    .contents()
    .find('a.anchorLink')
    .on('click', clickHandler);
})
```

Comment: Its not working . Not able to navigate to first link itself if use on click

Comment: Please help its not working

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay, can you post code of your example implementation or link your code?

Comment: This is wat is happening  https://imgur.com/5IOJtod . Please help

Comment: Sorry, I need to see implemented code, not the result.

Comment: i have updated the question. Implemented code is it html page?

Comment: Sorry but from what I can see you don't follow my suggestion. You have to encapsulate the click event using "on" instead of find and click events together.

Comment: @suhaas please see my edits

Comment: Code is not working . I used find because #frmdisplay is an iframe.

Comment: Please, can you post your code with my changes?

Comment: Updated code in question

Comment: @suhaas please refer to my last answer.

Comment: Thanks its working.